# QRubberBand colour isn't changed under Mac

Tags: qt

This code draws QRubberBand in blue colour under Windows but it doesn't work under MacOs. And I wonder why?

```
QRubberBand *rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this->imageLabel);
rubberBand->setGeometry(rec);

QPalette palette;
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Highlight, QBrush(Qt::darkBlue));
rubberBand->setPalette(palette);
```

Comment: Maybe it is this known "feature" (from http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37405-QRubberBand-make-background-invisible): By default a rectangular rubber band (s is Rectangle) will use a mask, so that a small border of the rectangle is all that is visible. Some styles (e.g., native Mac OS X) will change this and call QWidget::setWindowOpacity() to make a semi-transparent filled selection rectangle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've resolved it this way:

```
QRubberBand *rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this->imageLabel);
rubberBand->setGeometry(rec);

QPalette palette;
QColor color(Qt::blue);
color.setAlpha(80);
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Highlight, QBrush(color));
rubberBand->setPalette(palette);
```

Now rubberband is the same under MacOS and Windows.